# How to progressively populate columns in Excel based on changing a counter using formulas

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm not too familiar with VBA programming, so if this is able to be done with formulas that would be great.

I have a spreadsheet that is tracking a weeks worth of inputs, so I have 7 columns that I need to fill out. Each cell under the columns has a bunch of formulas built in that calculates the change in a pool of money for any given day.

I'm trying to get the sheet working so that all I have to do is change one cell, a "Day" counter, and the cells underneath that day would automatically populate WITHOUT changing the values of the previous column. So, as each day happens, all I'd need to do is to change the number in the Day cell and excel would know to populate the next column.

Here's an example of how it should work:

Day cell set at 1

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7  
-4  
-6
```

Change Day cell to 2

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7   
-4 -2  
-6 -1
```

Is there a formula to pull this off?

Comment: What does the raw data look like that the formulas would rely on? Surely you'd have to also change/append this data in the spreadsheet in addition to changing the `Day` cell.

Answer (score 1):

Populate all fourteen cells with the required formulae wrapped in an IF statement that returns blank unless the day number is less than or equal to that you specify.